# assembly-time evaluation of floating-point expressions

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, expression, tasm

I am currently familiarizing myself with the possibilities of Turbo Assembler 2.0; I was
happy to find out that float constants can be specified as follows.

```
SomeVariable dd 72.0; corresponds to 042900000h
```

I was assuming that it is possible to evaluate expressions at assembly-time, like

```
SomeVariable dd 1.0 / 4.0; does not assemble
```

however this seems to be impossible. Is there indeed no possiblity to generate constants even
from relatively simple expressions at assemble-time?

Comment: Turbo Assembler 2.0? [Retrocomputing.SE] SE is that way <--- :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For FP math, I'm not surprised some (most?) assemblers choose not to do assemble-time eval.  That would raise questions like what rounding mode, and what intermediate precision if the expression is more than one operator?

Most assemblers do integer constant-expressions just fine, including with `equ` and equivalent `foo = 123` named constants.

Comment: In a real address mode assembler that I wrote, every numerical expression is evaluated with FP math. The rounding mode is the FPU's default 'round to nearest' and all intermediate results are stored in the 80-bit extended precision. I chose this path to save me from using an external calculator; now I has one built-in!

Comment: @SepRoland: Interesting choice.  Sure you can just define some specific semantics. That wouldn't work for NASM or GAS, though. They're portable and can work as cross-assemblers, written in C.  You can compile and run NASM on a PowerPC to create bit-identical x86 machine code to what you'd get from assembling the same file on an x86 machine.  Emulating 80-bit x87 evaluation of expressions in portable C would not be a fun time.  This is a TASM question it seems; IDK what TASM was written in, perhaps Borland Turbo C++.  They *could* have used `long double`, but it had to run on no-FPU machines.